# Python Data Scraping: Scraping through the title with series of href and prettify doesnt work

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a newbie in Python, and my first try is to do some web scraping from a random site. this is my code and I am confused on what is the turn around into this.

I am scraping for the title and the size of the episode but it has 2 `href` and prettify doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-tv').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

tvhead = soup.find('tbody')
filename = tvhead.tr.find_all('td',class_='coll-1 name')
print(filename)
```

Now, I wanted to scrape the title and the file size of that episode then loop for all of them in that page. and I am confused. Please help.

But before this I was able to get just the title with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-tv').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for tvtitle in soup.find_all('td',class_='coll-1 name'):
    a = tvtitle.find_all('a')[1].text
    print (a)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are probably trying to achieve something like this:

```
filenames = tvhead.find_all('td',class_='coll-1 name')
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename.get_text())
```

Keep in mind that when you used `.tr` with BeautifulSoup, it will give you only the first `tr`, similar to what `find` instead of `find_all` would do.

Comment: Yes this is correct. I also wanted to filename and filesize be printed together like `filename
filesize
filename
filesize`

Comment: `filename = tvhead.find_all('td',class_='coll-1 name')
filedate = tvhead.find_all('td',class_='coll-date')
for filename in filename:
    print(filename.get_text())
    print(filedate)
    print()`
@kevin-kamonseki still can clear the date with get_text, it gives me error